# Is there a library of standard XML formats and is using standard the right choice for design?

Tags: xml, standards

I was wondering generally if there are any resources for finding XML standard formats.

If you don't find a standard format for the data you will be consuming in your application, would you create the standard yourself and submit it somewhere?

And beyond help finding locations of standard xml and xsd

Comment: Comment would be greatly appreciated how I could improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_markup_languages . The W3C creates and manages many XML standards , as does the OASIS organization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OASIS_%28organization%29.

The difficulty with XML or other standards is not creating them, but getting widespread community use.

If you have generic data you could use XSD Dataypes to ensure the type of the object (e.g. xsd:double, xsd:uri). The structure of your data will be personal to your application unless you are using an industry standard. At this stage most people will create a local schema. Even things like addresses are non-trivial - they depend greatly on locale.

If you use namespaces you can often create your own applications by using elements from more than one existing schemas.

Comment: Even if only I used it, it would be standard format for my application and anyone else who wanted to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Robin Cover, who produced the Cover pages where you found this spec, used to do a brilliant service to the community by summarizing all these specs. Sadly he got overwhelmed by the sheer number of them and gave up quite a few years ago.

One of the problems with specs like the Address Data one is that they are put together by industry groups with a very deep and broad understanding of the problem, who are inclined to cover every corner case that any of their members can come up with. Most of us can get by with a form that asks us what city we are in, even though most of us don't live in cities; we make do, and it works. But it's not good enough for the experts. You have to decide whether you need the complex modelling that's possible with such specs or whether you can make do with something cheap and cheerful.